# One channel audio

Tags: audio

When I record sound with my Samsung 9, with *all* the different apps (4 or 5) I've tested up to now, including the default one, the resulting file is one-channel.  Why?  Is there a way - if any - to have a 2-channel file as a result of an audio record via Android smartphone?  Thanks for any help.

Rodolfo

Comment: Have you tried to attach an external stereo microphone?

Comment: Yes, I did record trough an external microphone connected to the smartphone via a small USB sound card: and the result is still 1-channel.  The same microphone connected in the same way to the PC records in 2-channel mode.